# set different ids inside for loop

Tags: c#, html, razor

I want to set different ids.

The first one will be: id1

the second: id2.

till ths last: id6.

how can I do that?

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    <img id="id + @i" src="img.jpg">
}
```

Comment: its impossible as you have seven elements and you assign only 6 ids :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    <img id='@("id" + i)' src="img.jpg">
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Just use a loop for i = 1 to 6:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    <img id="id + @i" src="img.jpg">
}
```